# Send Audio File with paho mqtt

Tags: python, mqtt, publish-subscribe, iot, paho

I want to publish a `.wav` file to the broker. After that I want to subscribe this `.wav` file and write it into new file.

The audio file is 3.4MB large.

The code works fine if the file isnt that large, for example a picture with the size 56kb works without any problems.

I'm using Python 2.7 and the libary paho-mqtt

Publish Code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

topic = "/voice/"

#Die Variablen sind bei mir im Skript entsprechend angepasst 
user = "user"
pw = "passwort"
host = "X.cloudmqtt.com"
port = 116123

def on_message(client, obj, msg):
    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.qos) + " " + str(msg.payload))

mqttc = mqtt.Client()

mqttc.on_message = on_message

mqttc.username_pw_set(user, pw)
mqttc.connect(host, port)

f = open("name.wav", "rb")
imagestring = f.read()
f.close()
byteArray = bytearray(imagestring)

mqttc.publish(topic, byteArray)

rc = 0

while rc == 0:
    rc = mqttc.loop()
```

Subscribe Code

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

topic = "/voice/"

#Die Variablen sind bei mir im Skript entsprechend angepasst 
user = "user"
pw = "passwort"
host = "X.cloudmqtt.com"
port = 116123

def on_message(client, obj, msg):
    print("Write")
    f = open('new.wav', 'wb')
    f.write(msg.payload)
    f.close()

mqttc = mqtt.Client()
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.username_pw_set(user, pw)
mqttc.connect(host, port)

mqttc.subscribe(topic, 0)

rc = 0

while rc == 0:
    rc = mqttc.loop()
print("rc: " + str(rc))
```

After a while im getting a rc: 7. And the subscriber interrupt the process.
Thx for the help

Comment: Presumably your mqtt server isn’t actually on port 116123 - port numbers are in range 1-65535. Also MQTT topics can but should not start with a leading / (ref https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices) and a trailing / doesn’t mean anything

Comment: Oops “mqtt broker” not server

Comment: Have you checked the payload size limits of your mqtt broker?Presumably 3.4Mb is too large.

Comment: MQTT messages can be up to 256mb, 3.4mb should not be a problem

Comment: Indeed. But still worth confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Error 7 means that the connection has been lost. I would check the broker logs to see if it closed the connection for a reason.

Since you are only sending 1 message you should be able to just use the [single](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#single) publish shortcut that will handle everything for you:

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

topic = "voice"

#Die Variablen sind bei mir im Skript entsprechend angepasst 
user = "user"
pw = "passwort"
host = "X.cloudmqtt.com"
port = 116123

f = open("name.wav", "rb")
imagestring = f.read()
f.close()
byteArray = bytearray(imagestring)


publish.single(topic, byteArray, hostname="host",auth = {‘username’:user, ‘password’:pw})
```

Also topics should not end with a `/` and while allowed by the spec it is a bad idea to start them with a leading `/`